# "No screens found" while starting Xorg with startx after installing Nvidia drivers in Virtualbox

Tags: xorg, virtualbox

I installed Arch i686 on a VirtualBox VM (I have an nvidia GT610). I ran the following command as root:

```
pacman -S nvidia
```

After installation and rebooting, I ran

```
pacman -S xorg-server xorg-xinit xorg-server-utils xorg-twm xorg-xclock xterm
```

then

```
startx
```

I got a fatal error saying `No screens found`. Any help as to what should I do ?

Answer (score 8):

I was having this problem too while installing arch on Virtualbox. It was fixed after I did the following:

1. Execute the following to install "mesa" and virtualbox support:

   ```
   pacman -S mesa xf86-video-vesa
   pacman -S virtualbox-guest-utils
   ```
2. Open `/etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox.conf` with nano:

   ```
   nano /etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox.conf
   ```

   and write the following lines in the file:

   ```
   vboxguest
   vboxsf
   vboxvideo
   ```

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> , enter <kbd>Y</kbd> to confirm that you want to "save and exit", and when it asks for the filename hit <kbd>Return</kbd> without changing the name.
3. Reboot by running:

   ```
   reboot
   ```
4. Install the following packages, if you have not already (I had them installed before, so I skipped this part):

   ```
   pacman -S xorg-twm xorg-xclock xterm
   ```
5. Restart X:

   ```
   startx
   ```

Answer (score 3):

> I Installed Arch in virtualbox

A virtual machine running in vbox uses a emulated video card instead of your nvidia card.

Which means nvidia like driver is unnecessary.

Try `X -configure` first, which will generate a probed xorg config, but modern Xorg shouldn't need that at all. 
(If you have /etc/Xorg/xorg.conf, remove it)

Comment: This didn't help. `X -configure` returns `No device to configure. COnfiguration failed. Server terminated with error (2)`.

Comment: For 10 years people go around telling people that this shouldn't be needed. It's simply not true. Too often, it is needed. Please stop pretending it works. It would be nice if it did, and yes, it should. Should is irrelevant.